# regex for accepting a-z letters and composite keys in angular

Tags: angular, regex, input

i like to limit input to accept only [a-z] letters and also composite keys like ctrl+A , ctrl+C , etc to handle natural behavior of html input . how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]">
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This is good but it works after data entry . i like to prevent user to enter unexpected characters during data entering. I think i have to work on some events such as Keydown and prevent some characters which i don't like them .